# 1+1D curved spacetime diagram example

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, curvature

This is a very basic question about General Relativity. I haven't take any GR course yet.

Suppose a flat spacetime with one space direction and one time direction, as follows:

[image: 1+1D flat spacetime.]

Now add a mass at rest at $x_0$. The world line of this mass can be drawn in the spacetime diagram as follows (red line):

[image: The world line of the mass.]

Now I wonder how the constant time and constant space lines would look like?, i.e. I would like to depict the grid of this spacetime.

My reasoning (may be wrong) was as follows: Over the $t$ axis I marked down the units of time. Then, I know that inside a gravitational field clocks run slower, so I marked down (over the mass' world line) the slower units of time. Like this:

[image: ASD]

What I did next was just to join these marks as follows:

[image: Constant time lines]

I don't care about the exact shape of the *constant time lines*, I just want to know if this reasoning is good.

I also wander how are the *constant space lines*... If I consider the following

[image: This may be wrong...]

then a very small test mass placed at rest at some $x$ near the big mass will eventually feel an attraction and at $t\to\infty$ will collide with the big mass. This must be wrong because in real life masses do not need infinite time to fall. But I cannot manage to find the *constant $x$ lines*.

Comment: Have you considered drawing some lightcones across the whole grid? In Minkowski space these should all look the same. Then ask yourself if the grid you've drawn is consistent with that. Can you draw smaller lightcones that follow the grid you've drawn? What do they look like as you approach the mass? Playing with this should give you some insight.

Comment: On what platform did you create these illustrations?

Comment: @Olivier it is [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Your constant space lines are good, but the test mass doesn't need infinite time to reach the large mass.

## Constant time lines

In your diagram, a "unit of time" has the same interval but different lengths at different positions. So the interval must be the proper time, which is the time an object experienced in its proper frame. And the length must be the proper time of a mass at the origin.

Say we have John at the origin, and Mary on the large mass. Since "inside a gravitational field clocks run slower", a full year experienced by Mary, in her proper frame, seems longer than one year to John. This is depicted by the comparison between the blue and green "unit of time"s.

So your reasoning about the constant time lines with your diagram is correct.

## Constant space lines

If the interval between two constant space lines is the distance Mary experienced, your reasoning about the lines is good. The interval between $x=1$ and $x=2$ stays $\Delta x=1$, but the length we see gets larger. John would think that an object travels more than $\Delta x=1$ from $x=1$ to $x=2$ because he sees what we see.

Things become clearer if the red line is the world line of a small black hole. In this case, John and we would stretch the length between lines of $x=1$ and $x=2$ to infinity. If Mary travels across the blackhole from $x=1$ to $x=2$, she will experience a distance of $\Delta x=1$ to find John dead infinite years ago.

## Freefallers

Assume that an apple is placed at $x=1$. If there is no red line and the spacetime is flat, the apple just follows the straight line $x=1$. In the curved spacetime with a large mass at $x=1.5$, the apple follows a "straight" line as well, but the line is "straight" only if you put it in Riemannian geometry.

In general relativity, a mass moves along geodesics in the curved spacetime if it is free from any forces. Geodesics are straight lines in a curved spacetime.

Back to the diagram, the apple will follow some sort of arc starting from $x=1$, and it will reach the red wordline in a finite time interval.

[image]

## References

If you are looking for a curved 2D spacetime visualized in 3D space, this link may be helpful: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/visualize-2d-intrinsic-curvature-of-spacetime-1s-1t-in-3d.996487/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/430138)

Answer (score 0):

You take the 'black axis' in some sense as 'the' reference. Taking this time as reference, though, you construct the so called constant time-lines: they are not constant at all, but I think you want us to interpret this line of events as events that (straight line to the left, curved line to the right) will be simultaneous for observers following the black world-line. So, taking a particular $t_1$ in $t$, to the left - more or less - the simultaneous events occur (following this $t$ world-line) as a straight line, to the right as a curved line.

But still I can not realize the question with relation to the coordinate system. x = constant remains the same (as long as t = constant).

What can be said about the example is that a 'space interval' (thin road, f. e.) that approaches the red world line will look 'smashed' nearby it.

Still the influence of a small mass can be taken via Schwarzschild solution in $(t,x,y,z)$-coordinate system (found in wikipedia). Im not sure you can simply ignore $y$ and $z$, though (as long as they are not Killing vectors).